# "Swap file xxx already exists" when editing apache configuration file in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

Using vim I keep getting a message saying "Swap file xxx already exists" when I'm editing an apache config.  However, I don't see it in the working directory on in tmp.  How do I delete this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Vim swap files are normally hidden (Unix hidden files begin with a `.`). In order to view hidden files as well as regular ones, you need to `ls -A` (mnemonic: A for All). That should show you whether a swap file is there or not.

Answer (score 11):

This happens only when the file you were trying to edit is not saved completely on to the disk. Scenarios are :

1. You shut down your system improperly, when a file is still open in vi/vim.
2. when your file is being accessed concurrently via different/same
       consoles in vi.

vi/vim creates a .swp file whenever a file is opened in vi/vim. Everytime a file is opened in vi/vim, vi/vim checks for this file and if found this warning pops up

This is can be avoided in two ways

1. one by deleting the .swp file which is named as

"path/of/the/file/you/were/editing/.your_file_name.swp"

1. you can also opt for recover mode of vi/vim when opening the file
   and pressing recovery option .

I am just talking about the first scenario and it is safe for only that scenario. Scenario second is the different case.

Comment: If there were unsaved changes, you can recover them using `vi -r` (or `vim -r` if you prefer).  I usually write the recovered file to a temporary file and `diff` it against the main file.  (I don't quite trust the recovery not to lose information.)

Answer (score 1):

In the message, you should see the full path to the file. You can rm it by copy-pasting the path as follows:

```
rm -f /path/to/the/file
```

Answer (score 1):

If the file you're editing is called `httpd.conf` then the swap file will be called `.httpd.conf.swp`. It is hidden unless you add `-a` to your `ls` arguments.

```
ls -a /etc/httpd/conf/
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the swap file in Linux use this command

```
rm .filename.swp
```